# Make every project that uses my certain static-library link to a certain external library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, linker

This is about work-flow / ease of managing Visual Studio project.

## Project Structure

I have a solution that contains 2 projects.

### Structure 1

- project `B` (static-library) : Use function from an external library (e.g. [`Bullet3d`](http://bulletphysics.org/))

  - include `Bullet`'s header
  - link to `Bullet`'s `.lib`  (roughly speaking)*
- project `C` (application) : Use function/class from `B`, never touch `Bullet` directly

  - include `B`'s header
  - link to `B`'s `.obj`

[*] As far as I know, [a static library doesn't concern about what it links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198261/link-static-library-in-another-static-library) (+[another similar link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858560/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-library-chain)).
The above tree just describes what I want.

As I tested, the above structure causes `unresolved external symbol error`.

### Structure 2

It works OK.  Here is the structure :-

- project `B` :

  - include `Bullet`'s header
- project `C` :

  - include `B`'s header
  - link to `B`'s `.obj`          <------ X
  - link to `Bullet`'s `.lib`     <------ Y

The **X** can be done easily in VS2015 :-

- Right click the word **References** of C in **Solution explorer**".
- Then, add `B`.

The **Y** can be done by setting `C`'s **project property** or (more advance) manipulate **property sheet** that `C` uses.

### Question

Although **structure 2** works, it is inconvenient and not intuitive for me.
 Whenever a project (e.g. `C`) want to ***import*** `B`, I will also have to do **Y** ,
i.e. manually link `C` to "`Bullet`'s library" (`.lib`).

Is there any technical approach/work-around (*syntactic sugar* of work-flow) that enable **structure 1**?

More specifically, I want a way to ***mark*** `B` as "Any one who refer to me will automatically link to `Bullet`'s `.lib`".

### Reference

There are many similar questions but these below questions are about **X** (project inside my solution) but not **Y** (automatically link to external project that is *not* a part of my solution).

- [Visual Studio 2010 not autolinking static libraries from projects that are dependencies as it should be supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depend)
- [What does the "Link Library Dependency" linker option actually do in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683869/what-does-the-link-library-dependency-linker-option-actually-do-in-visual-stud?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Note:** [**ar**-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries?rq=1) does not help, because **ar** is Linux-specific.

Comment: You can use `#pragma comment(lib, "acme.lib")` to the source, but this requires that your libs are somehow on the library search path.
You could alternatively use the properties editor to create a vsprops file that can add additional library directories, but again, people could forget to add the vsprops file to their projects.

Comment: Can vs create relocatable object files?

Comment: @Chris Becke   Thank, [`#pragma comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484434/what-does-pragma-comment-mean) is very useful.  I never heard about it.  XD

Comment: @Daniel Jour   I don't know what "relocatable object files" means.  I am still very new to project/solution concept, and also Visual Studio.   My knowledge about Visual Studio is probably a subset of yours.